# mapping servlet to serve my requests

Tags: servlets

I would like to map a servlet to serve the requests that includes 'app' and ends with *.html in the following way

```
<url-pattern>/app/*.html</url-pattern>
```

but on running the application it gives me an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> 
/app/*.html in servlet mapping
```

please help me to map that. And please provide me the links where I can learn about these url mapping rule and conventions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is indeed invalid. The wildcard has to be the first or the last character to indicate a suffix or prefix pattern respectively.

```
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
```

or

```
<url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
```

This is all clearly specified in Section 12.2 of [Servlet API specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html). Here's an extract of relevance:

> ## 12.2 Specification of Mappings
>
> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define
>   mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a `‘/’` character and ending with a `‘/*’` suffix is used for
>     path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a `‘*.’` prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string (`""`) is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
>     application's context root, i.e., requests of the form `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`.
>     In this case the path info is `’/’` and the servlet path and context path is
>     empty string (`““`).
> - A string containing only the `’/’` character indicates the "default" servlet of the
>     application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path
>     and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

To fix this, you have 2 options:

1. Use the `/app/*` pattern and do *not* put non-HTML files in `/app`. Put them elsewhere.
2. Use a different prefix pattern like `/controller/*` and create a `Filter` which is mapped on `/app/*` and does the following in `doFilter()` method:

   ```
   String uri = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
   if (uri.endsWith(".html")) {
       request.getRequestDispatcher("/controller" + uri).forward(request, response);
   } else {
       chain.doFilter(request, response);
   }
   ```

---

#### Related:

- [Design patterns in Java web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/) - contains simple MVC example

Answer (score 0):

When do you get this error? What app-server/web-server are you using? Also, please check if /app is being mapped somewhere else.