# How to create a JSF Filter/url-pattern to protect javascripts

Tags: javascript, jsf, resources, servlet-filters, url-mapping

I've written a Java web filter to handle my JSF application's security. I've the filter's mapping like this:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>authFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/login.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/*.js.jsf</url-pattern>    <--- invalid pattern
</filter-mapping>
```

and now i want to create a url-pattern to filter all javascript files. I'm using Primefaces, so the .js files are retrived in URLs like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyProject/javax.faces.resource/MyJavascriptFile.js.jsf?ln=MyLibrary
```

I cant filter the whole `javax.faces.resouces` because it also holds the CSS files. Is there a way to create a URL pattern to match only javascripts?

Comment: As a work arround, i added the pattern ```<url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource</url-pattenr>``` and treated the desired cases in the filter code

Answer (score 3):

```
<url-pattern>/*.js.jsf</url-pattern>    <--- invalid pattern
```

That's indeed an invalid URL pattern. The wildcard `*` can only be in the beginning or the end of the URL pattern. In your particular case, you do not need the `/` prefix at all.

```
<url-pattern>*.js.jsf</url-pattern>    <--- valid pattern
```

Note that this issue has **nothing** to do with JSF. Servlet filters are part of the basic Servlet API.

#### See also:

- [mapping servlet to serve my requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276297/mapping-servlet-to-serve-my-requests/5276439#5276439)

Answer (score 1):

The * wildcard functionality is limited in JSF, because only one * is allowed, and it must be **at the end** of the “form-view-id” string. For example, (any xml)
It works.

```
<from-view-id>/customer/*</from-view-id>
```

It will never match…

```
<from-view-id>/cus*mer/</from-view-id>
<from-view-id>/c*sto*er/*</from-view-id>
<from-view-id>*/customer</from-view-id>
```

[check out this page](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-add-a-global-navigation-rule-in-jsf/)