# Java web app - Deployment descriptor - URL pattern mapping

Tags: servlets, web.xml, web-deployment, url-mapping

What is the difference between the two URL mappings : /* and / ?

`<servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

   </servlet-mapping>`

What I understood after reading the specs is that :

The pattern /* will force everything through `MyServlet`.
The pattern / will make `DefaultServlet` as the default servlet in the app .

Both almost means the same to me . Please let me know if there is any specific difference ?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276297/mapping-servlet-to-serve-my-requests), [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/526534/Servlets/java/servlet-URL-mapping), and possibly [this](http://www.zomeon.com/3686420/servlet-filter-url-mapping). also, the [java servlet specs](https://jira.sakaiproject.org/secure/attachment/16135/servlet-2_4-fr-spec.pdf) may be of use.

Comment: @EliranMalka As a side note, you gave a link to the version 2.4 of the Servlet Specification, while the current one is version 3.0. Here is the link for [Java™ Servlet Specification Version 3.0](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)

Comment: thanks, @informatik01, that was for convenience sake - it was the only version i found exploded online for a quick reference, with no need to download.

Comment: @EliranMalka Oh, I see. Sorry about that ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the links , going through them I have compiled this answer . Let us see a sample `web.xml` :

**Case 1:**

`<servlet-mapping>

       <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>

       <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>`
`

In this case all requests `/context/` , `/context/anything` and `/context/sample.do` will invoke `servlet2` .

**Case 2:**

`<servlet-mapping>

       <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>

       <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>`
`

In this case requests like `/context/`, `/context/anything` invokes `servlet2` and `/context/sample.do` will invoke `servlet1`.